# Running gcc's steps manually, compiling, assembling, linking

Tags: c, gcc

If you have a simple C program, like

```
int main(void) {return 0;}
```

It can be compiled with  `gcc -o test test.c`.

As I understand, gcc performs compiling, assembling then linking. The latter two steps are achieved by it running `as` and `ld`.

I can generate the assembly code by using `gcc -S test.c`.

What would you type into a terminal, to convert the assembly code into an executable?

(the reason for doing so is to learn assembly)

Comment: Actually it performs preprocessing first, then compiling, then assembling, and then linking. The preprocessing maybe a nontrivial part of the process, especially if you use Boost...

Comment: You can use the `-v` parameter to see how GCC calls its subprograms, e.g. `gcc -o test test.c -v`

Comment: Check up by passing "-###" to gcc

Comment: @KerrekSB Would you add info about "Boost" tool?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

These are the different stages using gcc

```
gcc -E  --> Preprocessor, but don't compile
gcc -S  --> Compile but don't assemble
gcc -c  --> Preprocess, compile, and assemble, but don't link
gcc with no switch will link your object files and generate the executable
```

Comment: Current versions of GCC don't have a separate preprocessor anymore (you can ask for just preprocessing as above, though)

Comment: Nice answer, too bad it doesn't explain too much

Comment: If somebody like myself want to finally link as a separate command, only answer by ZeZNiQ shows how.

Answer (score 32):

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        printf("Hello World !\n");
        return 0;
}
```

For preprocessing, compiling, assembling and then finally linking the simple aforementioned hello world program, follow the steps below:

Step 1/4) Preprocess main.c to generate main.i:

```
$: gcc -E main.c -o main.i
```

NOTE: You could call the C preprocessor directly as well:

```
$: cpp main.c -o main.i
```

Step 2/4) Compile main.i to generate main.s:

```
$: gcc -S main.i -o main.s
```

Step 3/4) Assemble main.s to generate main.o:

```
$: as main.s -o main.o
```

NOTE: You can combine the aforementioned steps 1, 2 and 3 by using the -c (small C) flag of gcc:

```
$: gcc -c main.s -o main.o // OR $: gcc -c main.c -o main.o
```

Step 4/4) Link main.o with other necessary object files namely, crti.o & crtn.o (they define function prologs & epilogs, respectively), crt1.o (contains _start symbol for bootstrapping the initial execution of the program), libc.so path or -lc flag for libc and then finally set the name of the dynamic linker, to generate a dynamically linked ELF executable:

On x86_64:

```
$: ld /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o -lc main.o -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o main_ELF_executable
```

OR (if you'd like to specify path to libc.so)

```
$: ld /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so main.o -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o main_ELF_executable
```

On 32-bit ARM:

```
$: ld /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/crti.o /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/crtn.o /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o -lc main.o -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.3 -o main_ELF_executable
```

OR (if you'd like to specify path to libc.so)

```
$: ld /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/crti.o /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/crtn.o /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so main.o -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 -o main_ELF_executable
```

You can then run the ELF executable 'main_ELF_executable':

```
$: ./main_ELF_executable
```

> Hello World !

Sources:

> https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc
>
> https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld
>
> [https://dev.gentoo.org/~vapier/crt.txt](https://dev.gentoo.org/%7Evapier/crt.txt)

Comment: Was going to upvote, but you definitely shouldn't use a command line like that to link - let GCC call the correct linker command instead!

Comment: That's true, but the OP asked "What would you type into a terminal, to convert the assembly code into an executable?", so I just wanted to show how to perform every step manually. That's why I also posted the sources to encourage OP to learn more, including but not limited to, the fact that the linking order also matters.

Comment: If somebody like myself want to finally link as a separate command, only answer by ZeZNiQ shows how.

Answer (score 3):

`gcc test.s -o test` will compile the `test` from `test.s` for you.

[NASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netwide_Assembler) might also be worth your time -- it might be easier / more friendly than `gcc` for compiling assembly.

Comment: Not really. `gcc` handles a lot of system dependent bureaucracy for you, in full compatibility to how it handles other pieces of your project.

Answer (score 2):

After you do `gcc -S -o test.s test.c`, type `gcc -o test test.s`.

Answer (score 1):

As you may or may not know, the four stages of compilation are to preprocess (-E), compile to assembly (-S), assemble to object code (-c), and finally link.  The hardest for me to figure out was how to use the preprocessor output.  Here's how to do it:

```
gcc -E hello.c | gcc -S -xc -o hello.s -
gcc -c hello.s -o hello.o
gcc hello.o -o hello
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have `gcc` start and stop the compilation process wherever you want.  `gcc test.s -o test` will have it compile `test.s` from assembly into an executable.

Answer (score 0):

what I did was first I run the preprocessor by
`clang++ test.cpp -E > test.i`
then compiled it with ...
`clang++ -S test.i`
it should create a assembly file test.s ... then make the machine insturction file by
`as test.s -o test.o`
now you need to link it which is kinda confusing for dumb peoples like me ...
so we don't know the arguments for our last process which is linking ... to find out ... run
`clang++ -v test.s`
it should give you some big text of something ... find this line "-dynamic-linker" ... there's definately a -dynamic-linker in your output text ... now copy the text from -dynamic-linker to rest of the output ... just copy everything afterwards including "-dynamic-linker" ... now what i got is ...

-dynamic-linker /system/bin/linker -o a.out /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/11.1.0/../../../../lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/11.1.0 -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/11.1.0/../../../../lib -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/11.1.0/../../.. -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -L/system/lib /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/test-169b42.o -lc++_shared -lgcc -ldl -lm -lc -lgcc -ldl /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/11.1.0/../../../../lib/crtend_android.o

in this what you have to change is where your object file is ... in my case it is /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/test-169b42.o ... i need to change it to where my test.o file is ... /data/data/com.termux/files/home/CPP/Cpp_Log/hello_world/test.o ... this is where my test.o file is ...
so the argument we have to pass is ...

-dynamic-linker /system/bin/linker -o a.out /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/11.1.0/../../../../lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/11.1.0 -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/11.1.0/../../../../lib -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/11.1.0/../../.. -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -L/system/lib /data/data/com.termux/files/home/CPP/Cpp_Log/hello_world/main.o -lc++_shared -lgcc -ldl -lm -lc -lgcc -ldl /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/11.1.0/../../../../lib/crtend_android.o

now to link ... use the `ld` ... so the command is `ld args -o test` or in our case ...

`ld -dynamic-linker /system/bin/linker -o a.out /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/11.1.0/../../../../lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/11.1.0 -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/11.1.0/../../../../lib -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/11.1.0/../../.. -L/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib -L/system/lib /data/data/com.termux/files/home/CPP/Cpp_Log/hello_world/main.o -lc++_shared -lgcc -ldl -lm -lc -lgcc -ldl /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/11.1.0/../../../../lib/crtend_android.o -pie -o test` ...

since andriod 5+ can only run pie elf executables ...  i also added the "-pie" (position independent executable) before the -o test ...

now it should give you a executable file test ... just run it by `./test`

it should work