# Is it possible to use Two different linkers to create an executable file for the code compiled in any Compiler

Tags: linux, linker, linux-device-driver, compiler-optimization

This is regarding to the linker..
Can I use two different linkers to generate an executable for code compiled for Specific architecture.For Example I am using Tasking as a compiler,after compilation I got an Object files. I want to create a executable for the object files generated from Tasking using any other linker.

Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can run all the compilation steps separately and use different tools for any of them. The process is explained in the following thread:

[Running gcc's steps manually, compiling, assembling, linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527743/running-gccs-steps-manually-compiling-assembling-linking)