# How can I use CI in C Software, if all interfaces are not implemented?

Tags: continuous-integration

I have a question about CI, in a C project for embedded systems.

We are 2 developers, the one develops the hardware interfaces, like a function `get_timer_ms()`

the other developer develops the application software, like a function `wait(uint16 time_to_wait_Sec)`

Now is coming the problem, the developer with the application software is ready but the hardware interface developer is not ready.

The application developer commits the c code and the CI starts, compiling is successful and now is time to link. Linker throws an error `Unresolved external symbol`  and CI stops as uncompleted.

Is there a solution in this case? The developer has not a fault in the code but he cannot take a 'green' build of your code. How can I avoid it?

I am thinking about to write a script, to find out the unresolved external symbols, then to generate a C component with stubbed all the unresolved external symbols and try to link again the software, is this a good idea for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try, for now, would be to adjust your makefile(s) to only perform the compilation, without linking, see [Running gcc's steps manually, compiling, assembling, linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527743/running-gccs-steps-manually-compiling-assembling-linking).

I'm uncertain how much (throw away?) effort would be needed to get your script working reliably, maybe it'd be simpler to just give the other developer a hand with building that stubbed skeleton manually?

Comment: Manually is also an option, but I think with a script its not necessary to wait the other developer to do their job.